# How to select multiple rows at different place in a table using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying below code to fetch the table rows, but I need to select the rows which are at different place in a table.

```
    @Test
    public void testRowSelectionUsingControlKey() {
        List tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='iceDatTbl']/tbody/tr"));
        for(int i=0; i<tableRows.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(tableRows.get(i).getText());
        }
```

Comment: Your code prints all the rows, am I right? And you only want some of these? By which criteria do you want to select them? Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: I only wanted to select elements at different position in a table... don't confused with for loop, its just there to print the row, the solution provided below solves my purpose.... anyways thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select table rows at different position in a table you need to use Action Class and then you can use the CTRL buttons to select the elements that you want.
Lets say I need to select 1st and 4th row of a table, I'll do something like below:

For Example:

```
    public void testRowSelectionUsingControlKey() {
        List tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='iceDatTbl']/tbody/tr"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.click(tableRows.get(1)).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(tableRows.get(4)).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    }
```

Comment: Is, it what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

Above example is working perfectly with Selenium and C# with minor modifications below:

```
public void testRowSelectionUsingControlKey() {
    var tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='iceDatTbl']/tbody/tr"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.Click(tableRows[1]).keyDown(Keys.Control).Click(tableRows[4]).keyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
}
```

Comment: I have similar kind of case but i want to select from 1 to 5 rows (1,2,3,4,5) How can i do that ? I have done using Keys.Shift but another way ? 
public void testRowSelectionUsingControlKey() {
    var tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='iceDatTbl']/tbody/tr"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.Click(tableRows[1]).keyDown(Keys.Shift).Click(tableRows[4]).keyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform(); 
}

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
    public void testRowSelectionUsingControlKey() {
        List tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='iceDatTbl']/tbody/tr"));
        for(int i=0; i<tableRows.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(tableRows.get(i).getText());
        }
```