# how to select multiple rows of a table using selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I am working on selenium with java and want to select multiple rows (`WebElement`).
I am using following code to achieve this.

`new Actions().click(WebElement1).KeyDown(Keys.Control).click(WebElement2) click(WebElement3). KeyUp(Keys.Control). build(). perform();`

This code works fine in Firefox but not working in IE 9,10 or 11. In Firefox it select all 3 elements but in IE it always select last element. all 3 elements are available in visible when this code is getting executed.
I tried `moveToElement` also but nothing working in IE.
Any suggestions.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please post the link and code you are trying.

Comment: I tried above code using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632415/how-to-select-multiple-rows-at-different-place-in-a-table-using-selenium-webdriv & https://automateusingselenium.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/how-to-select-multiple-options-from-table-using-selenium-webdriver/ . both above code snippet working fine for firefox but not for IE.

Comment: Are you trying to select set of rows in grid